# Palabras <<borbotón>>

Tags: gramática, fonología

Recientemente, he visto una publicación en donde se relataba una especie de <<fenómeno fonológico>>.

He escrito <<palabras borbotón>> debido al gran exponente que resulta ser tal sustantivo: Palabras cuyo sonido simboliza, representa o deja a expectativa oral la cualidad o acción de su significado.

***Suenan a lo que son.***

¿Hay alguna categoría o alguna expresión previamente ya verbalizada ante esto?

Cuando dices “borbotón” tus labios se mueven como si brotara una erupción de agua.
Una bomba suena exactamente a algo pesado y redondo.

Consulto la definición apropiada a este apartado, debido a que, en primera instancia, consideré erróneo verlas con función onomatopéyica. No trata del <<guau, guau>> o el <<tic, tac>>.

Y, alzo la rama de la fonología, por interés en saber si lo determinante serían fonemas cuya vocalización conllevan o justifican su significado:

*—Si [i] es, por antonomasia, asociada a la idea de algo pequeño (tímido, fino)*

*—Si la “o” y “u” se relacionan a conceptos tenues, serios o, incluso, oscuros por la o no apertura bucal que implican(lúgubre).*

*Y no sé si más o menos lo mismo con ciertas consonantes.*

Agrego un par más de <<palabras borbotón>> de los que he visto:

***Antonomasia***

***Bomba***

***Quisquilloso***

***Rimbombante***

***Crocante***

***Taquicardia***

Agradezco cualquier ayuda e información dada.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido. Es interesante tu concepto de "borbotón", aunque creo que en algunos casos puede ser un poco subjetivo. Para mí, _antonomasia_ no me suena a nada, y _quisquilloso_ me parece una palabra graciosa, pero no creo que su sonido evoque la quisquillosidad. Sugiero estas otras: _vaho_ y _melifluo_.

Comment: Algunos ejemplos de _palabras con origen onomatopéyico_: **bárbaro, picar, enchufe, zigzag** (las onomatopeyas no son solo sonidos de animales). Ha pasado el tiempo, y estas palabras todavía "suenan lo que dicen", aunque ya no lo sepamos.

Comment: ¿'bárbaro'? ¿y el sonido de esa palabra a qué se parece?

Comment: @tac "_(...)los antiguos griegos (...) lo usaban para referirse a personas extranjeras, que no hablaban el griego ni el latín y cuya lengua extranjera sonaba a sus oídos como un balbuceo incomprensible (onomatopeya bar-bar-, similar a bla-bla-)._" De __[Bárbaro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A1rbaro)__ en Wikipedia.

Comment: he visto una publicación en donde se relataba una especie de <<fenómeno fonológico? Cual?//RAE: **Onomatopeya**: 1. f. Formación de una palabra por imitación del sonido de aquello que designa. Muchas palabras como quiquiriquí han sido formadas por onomatopeya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Palabras Ecoicas

Las *palabras ecoicas* son aquellas que imitan o sugieren el sonido de lo que están describiendo.

La palabra *ecoico* (*[definición de la RAE](https://dle.rae.es/ecoico)*) viene de *eco*.

- Chirriar: describe un sonido agudo y penetrante como el que hacen las
  bisagras oxidadas o los frenos de un automóvil.
- Cacarear: imita el sonido que hacen las gallinas cuando ponen huevos.
- Chasquido: describe el sonido seco y corto que hacen los dedos cuando
  se chasquean o el que hacen las ramas secas al quebrarse.
- Silbido: describe un sonido agudo y sibilante que puede ser producido
  por el viento, los pájaros o incluso los humanos.
- Goteo: describe el sonido de gotas de agua que caen en una
  superficie.

Comment: Como curiosidad la palabra-onomatopeya de una sartén en el fuego ("chirriante") en Inglés es 'sizzling' (también inspirada en el sonido del aceite caliente)

Comment: El Inglés está lleno palabras onomatopéyicas